# Prevent Google Analytics tracking pixel from redirecting for properties that have remarketing enabled

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pixel, universal-analytics

I've got an issue in our distributed application that when any web property in GA has remarketing enabled, our custom event tracker always 302 redirects to the marketing pixel but does not pass our custom app data along with it. Is there any way to prevent this?

Here is our code for reference:

```
var self     = this,
    type     = track ? 'conversion' : 'impression',
    campaign = self.getProp('campaign'),
    init     = self.getProp('ga_init'),
    gaObj    = false;

// If Google Analytics is not loaded, return early - they may have not added analytics.
if ( typeof window['__omGaTracker'] !== 'undefined' ) {
    gaObj = window['__omGaTracker'];
} else if ( typeof window['ga'] !== 'undefined' ) {
    gaObj = window['ga'];
}

// If the analytics object does not exist, return early.
if ( ! gaObj ) {
    return;
}

// Create a custom event tracker and dimensions if it has not been initialized.
if ( ! init ) {
    gaObj('create', id, 'auto', { 'name' : 'omTracker' });
    gaObj('omTracker.set', {
        'appName':    self.getProp('app_name'),
        'appId':      self.getProp('app_id'),
        'appVersion': self.getProp('app_version')
    });
    self.setProp('ga_init', true);
}

// Send the event tracking data to Google Analytics.
gaObj('omTracker.send', 'event', campaign, type, self.getProp('id').toString());
```

This works perfectly fine as long as remarketing has not been enabled for the web property where the custom event is being tracked. If remarketing has been enabled, a 302 redirect occurs.

Is there any way to prevent this, and if not, any way to ensure our data is passed properly? Otherwise, the events are not stored at all.